# making subtitles smaller and lower in html video texttracks

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have successfully created webpages with video-tags and JavaScript commands that add subtitles to the videos displayed in them.

However, the default mode makes rather large subtitles, and they are also quite high on the video.
I'd like to make them a little smaller, and lower.

My code generally looks like this:

```
cue1 = new TextTrackCue(33.633,35.193,"Anita and Zoe stare at the candles.");
cue1.id = '1';

myTextTrack.addCue(cue1);
```

or, if I want to put a carriage return, in the subtitle, I do this:

```
cue2 = new TextTrackCue(47.397,52.409,"Why is there so much care" + String.fromCharCode(10) + "Should we all beware?");
cue2.id = '2';
myTextTrack.addCue(cue2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no short ultimate answer. But you can try the `::cue` pseudoelement selector:

```
::cue {
    font-size: 60%;
}
```

Additionally you should use the `VTTCue` constructor if available, instead of the `TextTrackCue` constructor. You can do something like this:

```
if(!window.VTTCue){
    window.VTTCue = window.TextTrackCue;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/trixta/QZJTM/